# cakephp url argument in json format

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

I want following type of URL using cakephp.

```
http://localhost/project1/controller1/action1/[{"user_id":"1","udid":"","msg":"","nick_n":"Danis","post_t":"2011-10-21 12:15:00","source":"A"}]/50
```

where `[{"user_id":"1","udid":"","msg":"","nick_n":"Danis","post_t":"2011-10-21 12:15:00","source":"A"}]` and 50 are arguments.

I have written following line in /app/config/routes.php file.

```
Router::connect('/controller/action/*', array('controller' => 'controller1', 'action1' => 'actionName'));
```

But when I debug above URL, I am not getting the json formatted argument.

Here is my action.

```
function action1($arg1 = NULL, $arg2 = NULL) {
      // I am getting 50 in $arg1 and $arg2 = NULL.
}
```

Pls tell me if I have missed anything here. I am not getting the json formatted argument in $arg1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is beeing caused by the ":" character.

In CakePhp you can set [named parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration#Named-parameters-947) in the url so if you have an url like:

```
mysite.com/name:John
```

cake will generate the `$this->params['named']` array in the controller. In your case, cake will identify the ":" in the url and it will try to create the named parameter too.. unfortunately url-encoding the parameter won't solve the problem

you could change the separator for the named parameters.. but i'd say that the best way to proceed is to create a [custom route class](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration#Custom-Route-classes-1634) only for this particular url, and the rest of the site will use the normal route class

Hope this helps